# Conditional replacing of values ina a variable based on valuse in multiple other variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a following line of code which replaces a value in a variable (`var2`) based on a value in other variable (`var1`)

```
df$var2[df$var1 > 0] <- NA
```

However I would like to extend this and replace variables (e.g `var5`) in the data frame based on values in multiple other variables (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`) which are coded in specific columns 13:16.

I tried

```
df$var5[df[c(13:16)] > 0] <- NA
```

which would not work correctly and I would like to know why and how to optimally amend the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution, slightly modification based on your code

```
df$var5[rowSums(df[13:16] > 0)>0] <- NA
```

Note that `df[c(13:16)]>0` gives you a matrix, but you need just a vector to subset `df$var5`, so `rowSums()` can help you check if the whole row is fill with TRUEs.

**Example**

Given `df` as

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 4L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, NA, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L
), X3 = c(1L, 3L, 0L, NA, 0L, 3L, 0L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 
1L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 0L), X4 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, 0L, 
3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, NA, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L), X5 = c(0L, 
4L, 4L, NA, 0L, 0L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 2L), X6 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, NA, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 
NA, 0L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, NA, 0L), 
    X8 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L), X9 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 
    4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), 
    X10 = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, NA, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
    0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L), X11 = c(4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 4L, 1L, NA, NA
    ), X12 = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 2L, 4L), X13 = c(2L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, NA, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, NA, 3L, 
    4L), X14 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, NA, 
    0L, 4L, 3L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L), X15 = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 0L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, NA), X16 = c(4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, NA, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L), resp = c(1.86666666666667, 
    2.26666666666667, 1.5, 2.07692307692308, 1.92857142857143, 
    1.78571428571429, 1.92857142857143, 2.23076923076923, 1.73333333333333, 
    1.71428571428571, 1.46153846153846, 1.83333333333333, 2.35714285714286, 
    1.64285714285714, 2.6, 1.30769230769231, 2.66666666666667, 
    2, 2.66666666666667, 2.15384615384615)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16     resp
1   0  0  1  2  0  2  3  1  1  NA   4   3   2   3   2   4 1.866667
2   3  0  3  2  4  1  3  2  2  NA   4   1   4   1   2   2 2.266667
3   0 NA  0 NA  4  1  0  3  2   3   0   4   0   1   1   2 1.500000
4   1  4 NA  3 NA  4  4  0  2  NA   4   4   0   1   0   0 2.076923
5   4  4  0 NA  0  1  4  2 NA   3   3   3   0   0   3   0 1.928571
6   2  1  3  2  0  4 NA  4  2   1   1   3  NA   0   1   1 1.785714
7  NA  1  0  0  2  3  0  2  4   0  NA   0   4   3   4   4 1.928571
8   1 NA NA  3 NA  4  2  3  2   2   1   1   3   3   4   0 2.230769
9   2  0  1  4  1  3 NA  1  0   0   0   3   3   4   2   2 1.733333
10  2  3  2  0  1 NA  2  0  1  NA   4   0   3   4   1   1 1.714286
11  0  0  1  0  2  0 NA  3  3   0   4   0  NA  NA   3   3 1.461538
12  4  3 NA NA NA  2  2  0  1   3  NA   2   3   0   2   0 1.833333
13  4  2 NA  3  1  1  2  3  1   4  NA   0   4   4   2   2 2.357143
14  1 NA  1  4  3  2  3  1  3   0   1   0   1   3  NA   0 1.642857
15 NA  1  4  4  2  2  0  4  4   2  NA  NA   3  NA  NA  NA 2.600000
16 NA  1  1  3  4  0  0  1  0   3  NA  NA   0   0   0   4 1.307692
17  1 NA NA NA  1  4  3  1  4   4   4  NA   3   1   3   3 2.666667
18  0  3 NA  4  1 NA  1  1  4   3   1   3  NA   0   4   1 2.000000
19  4  3 NA  3  0 NA NA  2  4   0  NA   2   3   4   3   4 2.666667
20  4  3  0  3  2 NA  0  0  3   0  NA   4   4   1  NA   4 2.153846
```

then

```
df$resp[rowSums(df[12:16]>0,na.rm = T)>0] <- NA
```

such that

```
> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 resp
1   0  0  1  2  0  2  3  1  1  NA   4   3   2   3   2   4   NA
2   3  0  3  2  4  1  3  2  2  NA   4   1   4   1   2   2   NA
3   0 NA  0 NA  4  1  0  3  2   3   0   4   0   1   1   2   NA
4   1  4 NA  3 NA  4  4  0  2  NA   4   4   0   1   0   0   NA
5   4  4  0 NA  0  1  4  2 NA   3   3   3   0   0   3   0   NA
6   2  1  3  2  0  4 NA  4  2   1   1   3  NA   0   1   1   NA
7  NA  1  0  0  2  3  0  2  4   0  NA   0   4   3   4   4   NA
8   1 NA NA  3 NA  4  2  3  2   2   1   1   3   3   4   0   NA
9   2  0  1  4  1  3 NA  1  0   0   0   3   3   4   2   2   NA
10  2  3  2  0  1 NA  2  0  1  NA   4   0   3   4   1   1   NA
11  0  0  1  0  2  0 NA  3  3   0   4   0  NA  NA   3   3   NA
12  4  3 NA NA NA  2  2  0  1   3  NA   2   3   0   2   0   NA
13  4  2 NA  3  1  1  2  3  1   4  NA   0   4   4   2   2   NA
14  1 NA  1  4  3  2  3  1  3   0   1   0   1   3  NA   0   NA
15 NA  1  4  4  2  2  0  4  4   2  NA  NA   3  NA  NA  NA   NA
16 NA  1  1  3  4  0  0  1  0   3  NA  NA   0   0   0   4   NA
17  1 NA NA NA  1  4  3  1  4   4   4  NA   3   1   3   3   NA
18  0  3 NA  4  1 NA  1  1  4   3   1   3  NA   0   4   1   NA
19  4  3 NA  3  0 NA NA  2  4   0  NA   2   3   4   3   4   NA
20  4  3  0  3  2 NA  0  0  3   0  NA   4   4   1  NA   4   NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not understand the ==4 element. Could you please explain?

Comment: @EvaBalgova the number of columns from 13 to 16

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding, this does not work for me and I am not sure why. It works fine with one variable, but not when I want to use a range of variables. I have a lot of NA's in the data and tried to add ```na.rm = TRUE``` to the code line but it still does not change var5 to NA despite values greater than 0 in the other variables.

Comment: @EvaBalgova you did right by adding `na.rm = T` when having `NA`. however I have no idea what's the error without seeing your real data

Comment: There is no error, the code executes fine, just the values in var5 do not change at all and stay as they are.

Comment: @EvaBalgova You said " It works fine with one variable, but not when I want to use a range of variables". Do you mean one variable for one column?

Comment: The specific example I am using is: ```FER_TMS_nopractice_recoded_replaced$SCRAM1.RESP[rowSums(FER_TMS_nopractice_recoded_replaced[c(12)] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)==1]<-NA```This works well and changes the values in SCRAM1.RESP for those rows where FACE.RESP>0, hovever for
```FER_TMS_nopractice_recoded_replaced$SCRAM5.RESP[rowSums(FER_TMS_nopractice_recoded_replaced[c(12:16)] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)==5]<-NA``` SCRAM5.RESP remains as it is despite values greater than 0 in columns 12:16.

Comment: @EvaBalgova see my updates with an example with dummy data, it works well

Comment: Thanks @ThomaslsCoding, however the rule you applied changed resp to NA if none of the columns 12:16 was 0. I need to change resp to NA if there is a value greater than 0 in any of the columns 12:16. For example, row 3 of resp should have also changed to NA as X12, X14, X15 and X16 are values bigger than 0. Basically, resp should remain unchanged if X12:X16 are all 0 or NA or a combination of 0 and NA. Any other value in any of the 12:16 columns should lead to replacing the value in resp to NA. Many apologies for not being able to be very clear.

Comment: @EvaBalgova I guess I got your point now... you have `or` conditions over columns, rather than `&`, is it?

Comment: @EvaBalgova I guess what you need is `df$resp[rowSums(df[12:16]>0,na.rm = T)>0] <- NA`. You can check my updates

Comment: I know that comments like this are not very welcome here, but I can't help it. @ThomaslsCoding that isBrilliant! Works now. Very happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First some.dummy data

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(
 "V1" = rnorm(10,0,1),
 "V2" = rnorm(10,0,1),
 "V3" = rnorm(10,0,1),
 "V4" = rnorm(10,0,1),
 "V5" = rnorm(10,0,1))
```

Then for one variable

```
dt1[V1 < 0, V6 := NA]
```

And for multiple

```
dt1[V1 < 0 & V2 < 0 & V3 <0, V5 := NA]
```

Comment: rg255, thanks for your reply. ```dt1[V1 < 0 & V2 < 0 & V3 <0, V5 := NA]``` changes V5 to NA if all the variables are <0, I would need to change V5 to NA if any variable v1:v3 is <0.

Comment: ```dt1[(V1+V2+V3) < 0, V5 :=NA]``` solved my problem, however it does not work on my real data set. I do have a lot of NA values in all variables and I am wondering if that could be a problem and if so, how to deal with it so that the NA values are treated as 0.

Comment: Substitute the `&` for `|` (the "or" conditional operator)

Comment: Also, use `!(is.na(V1))`... (or without the exclamation mark as needed) to deal with the NAs

Answer (score 0):

You can can get a better understanding by looking at smaller parts of your code.

First look at `df[c(13:16)] > 0`: the result is a matrix with just `TRUE` and `FALSE` in it. In particular you cannot use `df$var5[df[c(13:16)] > 0]` because the inner object is a matrix and you cannot subset a vector with matrix.

So what can you do? You can use `apply` to transform this matrix into a vector:

```
idx <- apply(df[c(13:16)] > 0, 1, all)
```

This will result in a vector which contains `TRUE` if all elements in a row are `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise.
And finally you can use `df$var5[idx] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` answer. First, we create a dummy dataset. For printing purposes I have only created one with 10 variables, rather than the 16 you requested:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df <-
  replicate(9, sample(0:4, size = 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  set_names(paste0("var", 1:9))

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 9
#>     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     0     4     4     3     2     0     3     2     1
#>  2     3     4     1     3     1     3     3     1     1
#>  3     0     1     1     3     1     4     0     3     4
#>  4     1     1     0     1     4     0     4     2     1
#>  5     4     0     3     3     1     0     4     4     4
#>  6     2     4     0     0     0     3     0     1     3
#>  7     1     4     3     0     2     4     0     1     4
#>  8     2     0     2     3     2     4     2     0     3
#>  9     2     0     1     0     3     3     1     2     0
#> 10     0     4     1     1     2     4     1     2     2
```

Next, we conditionally `mutate` variable `var5` such that it is equal to `NA` only if all of the variables `var6:var9` are greater than `0`, and otherwise keep their original values:

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(
    var5 = ifelse(var6 > 0 & var7 > 0 & var8 > 0 & var9 > 0, NA, var5)
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 9
#>     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     0     4     4     3     2     0     3     2     1
#>  2     3     4     1     3    NA     3     3     1     1
#>  3     0     1     1     3     1     4     0     3     4
#>  4     1     1     0     1     4     0     4     2     1
#>  5     4     0     3     3     1     0     4     4     4
#>  6     2     4     0     0     0     3     0     1     3
#>  7     1     4     3     0     2     4     0     1     4
#>  8     2     0     2     3     2     4     2     0     3
#>  9     2     0     1     0     3     3     1     2     0
#> 10     0     4     1     1    NA     4     1     2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, we use the `|` operator to say 'or' instead of `&` to say 'and'. First, we create a new dummy dataset with many more `0`s for demonstration purposes:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df <-
  replicate(9, sample(c(rep(0, 10), 1:4), size = 10, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  set_names(paste0("var", 1:9))

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 9
#>     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0     1     0     4     0     2     0     0     0
#>  2     0     0     0     0     2     0     4     0     3
#>  3     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0
#>  4     0     0     0     0     0     0     3     0     0
#>  5     0     0     0     0     2     0     0     2     0
#>  6     3     0     4     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7     0     0     0     0     0     0     4     0     4
#>  8     1     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  9     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#> 10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     3
```

And now we replace `&` with `|`:

```
df <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(
    var5 = ifelse(var6 > 0 | var7 > 0 | var8 > 0 | var9 > 0, NA, var5)
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 9
#>     var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0     1     0     4    NA     2     0     0     0
#>  2     0     0     0     0    NA     0     4     0     3
#>  3     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0
#>  4     0     0     0     0    NA     0     3     0     0
#>  5     0     0     0     0    NA     0     0     2     0
#>  6     3     0     4     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7     0     0     0     0    NA     0     4     0     4
#>  8     1     4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  9     4     0     0     0    NA     0     0     1     0
#> 10     0     0     0     0    NA     0     0     0     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my aim is to replace the values in var5 not only if all of the variables in var6:var9 are >0, but if any one of these variables is >0. In other words if var6:var9 are all 0, then the value in var5 remains the same, as soon than there is a value greater than 0 in any of the variables var6:var9, then the value in var9 should become NA.

Comment: OK I understand - please see my edit in the answer above